# How to show -> and => as special characters in the IntelliJ Idea IDE?

Tags: intellij-idea

How can I show some symbols as special characters in the IntelliJ editor (for the Rust and Java languages), for example `->` as `→`?

Comment: It worked for me to do the following within the IntelliJ settings [Enable ligatures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70251769/8226543)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are searching for [font ligatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature).

> In writing and typography, a ligature occurs where two or more graphemes or letters are joined as a single glyph. An example is the character `æ` as used in English, in which the letters `a` and `e` are joined.

IntelliJ supports this by default in the `Settings -> Editor -> Font -> Enable font ligatures`:

[image]

Fonts supporting ligatures I'm aware of are:

- [Fira Code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode)
- [Iosevka](https://github.com/be5invis/Iosevka)
- [Hasklig](https://github.com/i-tu/Hasklig)
- [PragmataPro](https://github.com/fabrizioschiavi/pragmatapro)
- [monoid](https://github.com/larsenwork/monoid)
- [Ligaturizer](https://github.com/ToxicFrog/Ligaturizer)

Answer (score 4):

You're going to want to use a font which supports ligatures, such as Fira Code: https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode

Comment: In [FiraCode](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/wiki/Intellij-products-instructions) there re instructions for IntelliJ. In my case (version > 2018.1) that was enough:

   Enable in ```Settings → Editor → Color Scheme → Color Scheme Font → Enable Font Ligatures. ```
    Select Fira Code as "Primary font" under ```Settings → Editor → Color Scheme → Color Scheme Font → Font.```

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me to do the following within the IntelliJ settings

[image: enable ligatures]

Answer (score 0):

Enable in Settings → Editor → Color Scheme → Color Scheme Font → Enable Font Ligatures. Select Fira Code as "Primary font" under Settings → Editor → Color Scheme → Color Scheme Font → Font.